# How to run commands like sudo grails in ubuntu?

Tags: grails, ubuntu, path

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to run grails with sudo permission like:

```
sudo grails
```

but I'm getting:

```
sudo: grails: command not found
```

what should I do?

Comment: how did you install grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are executing the command inside the bin grails folder, you need to do:

```
sudo ./grails
```